ClientHeight and Height of a form updates when setting form to visible
On creation of a Form, I am setting MyPanel to not be visible:
constructor MyForm.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  TopPanel.Align := alTop; // parented to MainPanel
  MyPanel.Align := alTop; // parented to MainPanel

  MainPanel.AutoSize := True;
  AutoSize := True;

  if foo then
  begin
    MyPanel.Visible := False;

    // force client height to adjust and catch the not visible panel
    Visible := True;
    Visible := False;
  end;
end;

Without the Visible toggling, the Form's ClientHeight/Height acts as though MyPanel is still visible, including MyPanel's Height. Once I show the Form or toggle the Visible property, the ClientHeight will adjust to not include MyPanel's height. I would like to know if there is a better way to get the height to update without toggling the Visible property, as I am storing the ClientHeight on creation and it is not accurate by the time the form is shown.

Why are you setting all of these properties in the constructor's code at runtime instead of in the Object Inspector at design-time? Let the DFM do the work for you. Also, do you have your Form set to AutoSize=true?

I am setting the Form's AustoSize=true with those properties in the constructor.  It is set to false at design-time. I am setting these properties at runtime for no reason other than I find setting these at runtime gives me some more flexibility working in the editor.

I'm unable to reproduce the problem with the information you've provided.  But is MyPanel.Visible := False meant to be inside the if foo then begin ... end?  Also, is this form the main form, and if not, does it have Visible set to True at design time?

I put the MyPanel.Visible inside the if only to show that I am sometimes showing it and sometimes not. This is not on the main form, it is a custom form that inherits from TForm. MyPanel.Visible is set to True at design time and the form Visible is set to False.
